# How to get all the headers from an Angular 2 response?

Tags: angular, header, response

[image: Response in Chrome Dev Tools]

The response headers I see in Chrome Dev tools don't match the ones that Angular 2 is showing in the Chrome console.

[image: Only Content Type Showing Up]

Only the Content-Type header is showing up after having executed:

```
this.http.get(tempUrl).map(res=>{
      console.log("csrf received");
      console.log(res);
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only a certain list of "safe" headers are exposed by default (to Javascript). This is for security reasons. This list is as follows

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

In order to expose other headers, the server should send the access control header [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers), listing all the headers it wants to expose.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, X-CSRF-Token
```

Comment: Also sometimes you want to change in node code in app.js put 
this.app.use(cors({
      exposedHeaders: ['Content-Length', 'token'],
    }));  Ref . https://truetocode.com/set-and-get-custom-response-header-values-using-angular-5-and-express-js-node-js/