# Angular2: how to get custom response headers (CORS issue)

Tags: angular, response-headers

**Why can't I access ALL headers in Angular2 from the response?**

I have a legacy webservice which I can't modify. 
It sends some i,mportant information back to the client in the **Response headers**. Don't ask me why. this is crap.

[image]

my code is this:

```
      .subscribe((r: Response) => {
      var customHeader = r.headers.get("Database-Deleted");
      var allHeadersAsString = JSON.stringify(r.headers);
```

but seems the response contains only a few headers, not all of them.

Can someone tell me this is by design and there is no way to access them?
(or even better: tell me how to make it work)

**UPDATE**

Thanks top the comments I was able to identify it as a CORS issue. The accepted answers of other questions did not give me the right clue.

THANKS!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrictions of XMLHttpRequest's getResponseHeader()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462968/restrictions-of-xmlhttprequests-getresponseheader)

Comment: take a look at the “Cross-Origin Resource Sharing specification" of the answer : "specification forbids access to any response header field other except the simple response header fields (i.e. Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, and Pragma)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the headers from an Angular 2 response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306684/how-to-get-all-the-headers-from-an-angular-2-response)

Comment: If it's a CORS related issue, is there a way to allow it explicitly? Have to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a **CORS issue**. Thank you **n00dl3** for you comment!

If the server, in this case a C# WebAPI allows explicitly to expose the custom headers, then Angular2 allows me to access them.

This website helped me:
http://datawalke.com/c/webapi-owin-cors-and-custom-headers/

**Solution**

For testing I was able to allow all origins and list the custom headers I need.

```
    var att = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    att.ExposedHeaders.Add("Database-Deleted");
    att.ExposedHeaders.Add("Database-AlreadyDeleted");
    att.ExposedHeaders.Add("Database-DryRun");
    att.ExposedHeaders.Add("Database-Inserted");
    att.ExposedHeaders.Add("Database-Updated");
    config.EnableCors(att);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your back-end is ASP.net WebAPI Core, you have to do the following way

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination");
        }));
```